# The operator calculation of Helmholtz equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, operators, computational-physics, scattering, refraction

I am reading the **beam propagation method (BPM)** in optical imaging paper. I find a paper solve the **Helmholtz equation** in the **inhomogeneous media**. The paper is:

[*Light propagation in graded-index optical fibers, M. D. Feit and J. A. Fleck, Jr*](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-17-24-3990&id=22615)

They use the **operator form** to solve the equation, I never see this kind of operator calculation to solve the classical eletromagnetic proble before.  I can intuitively understand how it is going on. But I want to learn more about this and acquire such method. However, i am not a mathmatical stduent. **I don't want to learn a full book of the function analysis or some group theory to just acquire this**. I mean is there some good,**simple and not very long pages reading material** to learn this kind of technique.

Besides, there are some places that i don't understand in the paper.

1. Question 1:

Like the equation (3)

[image]

How to obtain this? Now the the expansion for $(1+x)^{1/2}$ is not hold for the Laplacian operator?

2. The second place i don't understand is:

[image]

Why it is equivalent to the Helmholtz equation? Intuitively, I know that using the angular spectrum to solve the Helmholtz equation, we can get maybe the top solution. However, is there or mathmatical derivation of this? From top to expression to the equation (10).

Comment: $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ for the former issue. The latter issue  may have some meaning in the sense of semi groups, using the identity of the former issue you raised and factorising the left hand side of the last written  equation.

Comment: Sorry I do not know books as you desire. A physicist usually learns how practically deal with this mathematical machinery when learning quantum mechanics…

Comment: Sorry, for the former issue can you say something more about that. Sorry for my stupid, i do not get your point.

Comment: For the second i also not get your point, pretty sorry. What do you mean of the factorising the left ahnd side of last equation. You mean factorising the Helmoltz equation or factorising the exp term? You say factorising mean thing like talyor expansion? Maybe, i am too stupid, i do not get your point.

Comment: For quantum mechanics, i learned some by myself. I know that it is filled with operator thing like momentum or Hamiltonian operator. But to be honesty, i do not have the ability to use such operator method to solve a general PDE like eletromagnetic problem. Do you have some book like some quantum mechanics book recommend, and which chapter i need focus on? @Valter Moretti

Comment: For example, i can understand, we can just take the operator as a number and use the number calculation rule for any commutator. However, for example, we can get equation (7) in the paper, but it still include the Lapacian operator. If we want to get the solution exact form, we still need to solve the PDE. Besides, it has the square root of  Lapacian operator plus a function, what is that, how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A := \sqrt{\nabla_\perp^2 + k^2I}$ and $B=kI$ where $k$ is a real positive number. Since $[A,B]=0$, it holds $$(A-B)(A+B) = A^2 +AB-BA -B^2 = A^2 +BA-BA -B^2 = A^2-B^2\:.$$ Hence
$$A = \frac{A^2-B^2}{A+B} + B\:.$$
That is your first identity.

Regarding the second issue, the equation you want to solve is
$$\left(\nabla^2_\perp + k^2 + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)E=0 \tag{1}\:.$$
You can factorize it as
$$\left(\sqrt{\nabla^2_\perp + k^2} + i \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\right) \left(\sqrt{\nabla^2_\perp + k^2} - i \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \right) E=0\:.$$
In summary, if you are able do solve both equations
$$\left(\sqrt{\nabla^2_\perp + k^2} \pm i \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\right) E_\pm=0$$
you are done by using twice the form of the solution.
As the paper declares on its first page, the solutions of the equations above are
$$E_\pm(x,y,z) = e^{\mp i z\sqrt{\nabla^2_\perp + k^2}} E_\pm(x,y,0)\:.$$
Using the initial identity,
$$E_\pm(x,y,z) = e^{\mp i z\left[\frac{\nabla_\perp^2}{\sqrt{\nabla^2_\perp + k^2}+ k}+ k\right]} E_\pm(x,y,0)
=e^{\mp i k z} e^{\mp i z\frac{\nabla_\perp^2}{\sqrt{\nabla^2_\perp + k^2}+k}} E_\pm(x,y,0)\:.$$
So, the information stored in
$$e^{\mp i z\frac{\nabla_\perp^2}{\sqrt{\nabla^2_\perp + k^2}+k}} E_\pm(x,y,0)\:,$$
taking the trivial phase $e^{\mp i k z}$ into account, permits to solve (1).
In this sense the said operation is ``equivalent'' to solve (1). I omitted a huge number of mathematical subtleties which do not affect the physical substance here.

**COMMENT**. Reading quite superficially the paper I realized that what I indicated by $k$ is actually a function of $x,y$ and not a constant. If it is really true my derivation does not hold, but also the your first identity  declared in the paper is false. It is of crucial relevance that $\nabla_\perp^2$ commutes with $k$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solve my question for long time. It looks like a black magic to me. I want to know how you acquire such technique. Like by reading some quantum mechanics book and doing some exercises? My research is more about classical optics or electromagetic problem. I read some paper that use some of the quantum mechanics's mathmatical method to handle the classic electromagnetic problem. But I do not have such ability to do it by myself. Do you have some reading material like some quantum mechanics book recommend, and which chapter i need focus on?  Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry I am basically a mathematician concerning this stuff,  so I am not the right person to ask. What you should look for is a practically minded book of **mathematical methods for engineering**.

Comment: For you question, unfortunately the $\nabla^{2}$ is not commuting with  k(x,y,z). You can check the book Introduction to Optical Waveguide Analysis: Solving Maxwell's Equation and the Schrodinger Equation, chapter 5, Beam Propagation Method. There is a prove of this. It is very simple, you definitely can prove it by yourself. However, i think you derivation still hold. Because this paper first assume that they are the commutator. Then the non commutator error can be estimated by formula called Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, or maybe just the Taylor expansion.

Comment: The error depend on how you split the k(x,y,z) with the Lapacian operator term, error will be like $O(\delta z ^2)$ or $O(\delta z ^3)$  As soon as the $\delta z$ is small enough, it won't cause many problem.

Comment: Ok it makes sense.

Comment: Regarding how I acquired my black magic: I actually teach these things, I make  research in this area,  and I also wrote several books on mathematical foundations of quantum theories. So it is a very long story...But my perspective is the one of mathematical physics instead you are more close to engineering or applied physics.

Comment: Sorry, can you have a specific recommendation of the book. I am Electrical Engineering student, I learned some book like Erwin's Advanced Engineering Mathematics book. But I do not see too much discription of such operator method. Maybe, i did not read it very carefully. I am not sure. Just want to let you know that i really thank you very much for your help and your time.

Comment: OK. I get it. Thank you for your answer anyway. Yes, maybe you are right. Because, actually I do not conern too much about the very rigor mathmatical derivation of it. It may not worthy for me to read a hundred pages mathmatical book just like you do. I also do not have such ability to do so like you.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: One last question: what is idea behind the first identity in your answer. Why people want to have such transformation? I do not get the idea behind it why people want to do so? what advantage this can bring to?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question

we pose : $x=\Delta_{\perp}\;\;, y=\frac{\omega}{c}n$

the second member of the equation becomes:

$\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+y}+y=\frac{x^{2}(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-y)}{(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+y)(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-y)}+y=\frac{x^{2}(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-y)}{x^{2}}+y=(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Thank you very  much.

Comment: what is idea behind this change. Why people want to have such transformation? I do not get the idea behind it why people want to do so? what advantage this can bring to?